# Basic DocPad: variables and first errors

Tags: html, coffeescript, docpad, eco

What I don't understand: certain keywords appear to be reserved for DocPad like @document, which words let me use custom data values?

e.g. I'm using

```
<%= data.hostimagesurl %>
```

but I've seen

```
<%= page.hostimagesurl %>
```

and

```
<%= site.hostimagesurl %>
```

also in use, can I make these up? Are there certain values I have to use?

I don't understand where I can discover the pitfalls, are hyphens and underscores allowed?

I'm imagining this works like handlebars, I define the tag enter the value and it just works - is this way of thinking correct?

I'm also confused to why my DocPad layout isn't working. I'm just getting an error

```
error: Something went wrong while rendering: /Users/***/my-new-website/src/render/index.html
The error follows:

ReferenceError: document is not defined
  at Object.eval (<anonymous>:55:29)
  at Object.eval (<anonymous>:67:8)
  at eval (<anonymous>:69:6)
  at Function.eco.render (/Users/***/my-new-website/node_modules/eco/lib/index.js:26:25)
  at EcoPlugin.render (/Users/***/my-new-website/node_modules/docpad-plugin-eco/out/eco.plugin.js:23:32)
  at ambi (/Users/***/my-new-website/node_modules/event-emitter-grouped/node_modules/ambi/out/lib/ambi.js:57:27)
  at Task.<anonymous> (/Users/***/my-new-website/node_modules/event-emitter-grouped/out/lib/event-emitter-grouped.js:45:23)
  at ambi (/Users/***/my-new-website/node_modules/ambi/es5/lib/ambi.js:98:14)
  at Domain.fireMethod (/Users/***/my-new-website/node_modules/taskgroup/out/lib/taskgroup.js:397:23)
  at Domain.run (domain.js:228:14)
  at Task.fire (/Users/***/my-new-website/node_modules/taskgroup/out/lib/taskgroup.js:435:27)
  at Immediate._onImmediate (/Users/***/my-new-website/node_modules/taskgroup/out/lib/taskgroup.js:452:26)
  at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

The first error I can see happens on this line:

```
background-image:url(<%= data.hostimagesurl %>bg.gif);

<body style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;min-width:100%; color:#353535; background-color:#f9f9f9; background-image:url(<%= data.hostimagesurl %>bg.gif); background-repeat: repeat; background-position:center top; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" yahoo="fix" bgcolor="#f9f9f9">
```

My render index.html file looks like:

```
---
title: "Welcome!"
layout: "default"
isPage: true

hostimagesurl: "http://www.googel.com/" 

---

<p>Testing 1</p>
```

What on earth am I doing wrong?

Comment: If hostimagesurl is sitewide then define it in your docpad.coffee script under templateData: hostimagesurl: "http://www.googel.com/" and use <%- @hostimagesurl%> in your html file  .Is your index.html file in the render folder and named index.html.eco so that it will render that file?

Answer (score 0):

```
@document
```

is just CoffeeScript (and eco) special syntax for

```
this.document
```

The variable `site` can be defined in your `docpad.coffee` file, see http://docpad.org/docs/begin and search for `docpadConfig`

I am still learning and cannot tell you about your `page.whatever` code but they are often used inside of a loop where the variable is named in the for loop code.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you've made the classic DocPad error of forgetting the `@` symbol when referring to the current document: `@document` is defined but `document` isn't.

Likewise, to access `hostimagesurl` you would need to call `@document.hostimagesurl`

By default two objects are passed to a DocPad template/page/layout. The `templateData` property defined in the docpad.coffee file and the current document object. These objects are properties of the template `this` context. In the case of `templateData` each of its properties are a member of the `this` context, whereas the document itself is a property of `this`.

In CoffeeScript and the CoffeeScript based template system, ECO, `this` is referred to by the `@` symbol.

What this means is that within an ECO template you access the current document with `@document`. You can also access `@site.url` or `@getPreparedTitle()` which are defined in the docpad.coffee file as part of the `templateData`.

The properties defined in the metadata section of your doc (between the `---`) are available as properties of the document object.

Quite often people will create variables like `page` when looping through a collection. These local variables don't need the `this` context. Typically something like this:

```
<%pages = @getCollection('pages').toJSON()%>
<ul>
    <%for page in pages:%>
        <li>
            <a href="<%-page.hostimagesurl%>"><%-page.title%></a>
        </li>
    <%end%>
</ul>
```